# How to split column value in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to split a column value which is not having space or any other delimiter. I searched the forums but I couldn't able to find the solution for my scenario.

**Here is my scenario**

```
ID   Column_Value
011  abcdefgh
```

**The result should be**

```
Column_Value1    Column_Value2
abcd             efgh
```

Comment: what is condition for split?

Comment: on what bases do you need to split it, if you have no delimiters? [according to this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-functions.html), you can use Left and Right functions based on length.

Comment: I need to split the value and print in to two columns, there is no other condition, can you post any example for this?

Comment: Split how??? Always 4 + 4 characters, or...?

Comment: Not always 4+4 characters, I just put it for example, split the value using index. Specify the index to split the value where to start and end according to our needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you just want to split a column down the middle, you can achieve this with a combination of [`substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) and [`length`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column_value, 1, LENGTH(column_value) / 2),
       SUBSTR(column_value, LENGTH(column_value) / 2 + 1)
FROM   mytable
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7ed3/6)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split the string based on the length and number of characters, then use **SUBSTR** as follows:

```
SQL> with data(str) as(
  2  select 'abcdefgh' from dual
  3  )
  4  select substr(str, 1, 4) col1,
  5         substr(str, length(substr(str, 1, 4)) +1) col2
  6  from data;

COL1 COL2
---- ----
abcd efgh

SQL>
```

Above, you could change the value of `4` to your desired value. Remember, both are not mutually exclusive.